# How do I configure privileges for a Standard user account?

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy, privileges

How do I limit the features of a Standard user account, *without* affecting the Admin account?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I'm assuming you're referring to the "default user" account?  You're trying to limit the feature of that account when setting up a machine, while trying to keep the Administrator account unaffected?  If so, this might sound strange, but Microsoft's recommendation is that you setup a pc the way you want it, and then you copy the Administrator profile to the default user account.  I used to do this when I administered a computer lab and it worked great.  It gave the default (student) account the rights I wanted it have, while keeping it limited, and not affecting the administrator account at all.