# How can I apply policies to Standard accounts?

Tags: windows-7, security-policy

How can I apply policies and restrict features, such as removing common program groups from the Start Menu, of Standard accounts without affecting Administrator accounts?

I found a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/172283/how-do-i-configure-privileges-for-a-standard-user-account), but it was for Windows XP and I was unable to implement the answer that was suggested.

Comment: What version of Windows 7?

Comment: @KCotreau Actually, I'm working on Multipoint Server 2011, but it's almost the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Group Policy, or you could use a much simpler tool called [1st Security Agent](http://www.softheap.com/newadmin.html)

1st security agent would work best if its just for one local computer

Comment: Yeah, I kinda figured it out by playing around. I used GPOs to configure 6 user's policies. Kind of a hassle, repeating everything in each object, but it was the best solution I could find.

Comment: hey AjaM, why didn't you vote my answer up?  you marked it as the answer, but didn't think it was any good?

Comment: Sorry. I'm still new to this website.

Comment: You don't have to remake each GPO.  You can just copy them or make templates.

Comment: @ AjaM I know, that why I reminded you. -_-.  Thanks.

Comment: @surfasb Where do I do that? I'm using GPO editor consoles.

Comment: @ AjaM, use the Group Policy Management snap in, not GPO editor snapin.

Comment: @surfasb I would have initially used the GP Management snap-in, but that requires a domain and I don't intend to have one, as it is a single PC.

Comment: @AJaM, Ya then it is a bit trickier.  Some suggest you can copy the Group Policy folder and export the security settings separately(They aren't stored in the same folder).  My suggestion is to download the Powershell script off the Microsoft scripting center.  Safer and you avoid the whole version number problem.